# Insert an image into a Gridview cell depending on text

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I use VS 2013 (VB) and asp.net.

I have a gridview created programatically using values from an MS SQL 2012 table.

The asp.net for the gridview is as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="availableRuns" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="Asset_table" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Asset_table_header" ></asp:GridView>
```

The VB code for the gridview is

```
    Dim RTORun As New RTO
    Dim RTORuns As New List(Of RTO)
    RTORuns = RTORun.getRTO
    availableRuns.DataSource = RTORuns
    availableRuns.DataBind()
```

I have another sub that I want to use to convert the values in the cells to images which is Currently used to change the text value.

```
    Protected Sub changeText()

    Dim row As GridViewRow

    For Each row In availableRuns.Rows
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            If row.Cells(i).Text = "1" Then
                row.Cells(i).Text = "Yes"
            ElseIf row.Cells(i).Text = "0" Then
                row.Cells(i).Text = ""
            End If
        Next

    Next
End Sub
```

This produces the following gridview

[image]

I want to be able to insert an image in replacement for 1 (or Yes as it is in the image) and leave it blank if 0.  I have no idea how to do this can anyone offer some pointers as googling hasnt helped as they all reference an image control in the asp.net page which I dont have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways - either direct HTML assignment:

```
If row.Cells(i).Text = "1" Then
                row.Cells(i).Text = "<img src='MyYesImg.jpg' />"
```

where "MyYesImg.jpg" is an image that exists in the same folder as your ASPX page. Also you have to make sure that grid columns have their `HtmlEncode` property set to `False` for image to propertly display.

Or, by programmaticaly adding Image Control (which you *do* have - it's a standard ASP.NET control, part of the framework)

```
Dim img As Image
'...loop code
If row.Cells(i).Text = "1" Then
    row.Cells(i).Text = ""
    img = New Image
    img.ImageUrl = "MyYesImg.jpg"
    row.Cells(i).Controls.Add(img)
```

Again "MyYesImg.jpg" is the image file that exists in the same folder as your ASPX page