# How to insert picture in gridview using path that is stored in text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to insert pictures from paths stored in text file. Text file looks like this:

AIPH7,iPhone 7 Plus 256GB__,Iphone,____,~/Pictures/iphone7plus.jpg______,999€______
ASZG0,Zenfone Go_________,Asus______,~/Pictures/zenphonego.jpg_______,138€______

I want to insert picture in gridview from that file location in text file. My gridview is auto generated by this function that reads all data from file and puts it into gridview:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\PC1\Desktop\Project\WebApplication1\file.txt";

public DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
      {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var cols = line.Split(',');
            DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
            for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < 5; cIndex++)
            {
                if (cols[cIndex].Contains('_'))
                {
                    cols[cIndex] = cols[cIndex].Substring(0, cols[cIndex].IndexOf('_'));
                    dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
                }
                else
                {
                    cols[cIndex] += '_';
                    cols[cIndex] = cols[cIndex].Substring(0, cols[cIndex].IndexOf('_'));
                    dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
                }
            }
            for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < 5; cIndex++ )
                if (dr[cIndex].ToString() == promenljiva)
                    tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        this.GridView1.DataSource = tbl;
        this.GridView1.DataBind();

        return tbl;
    }
```

After that i have:

```
ConvertToDataTable(filePath, 5);
```

This is the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert an image into a Gridview cell depending on text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227468/insert-an-image-into-a-gridview-cell-depending-on-text)

Comment: @IuriFarenzena it's not the same question, and for sure it's not duplicate

Comment: Yeah, maybe not duplicate, but it has the solution for you. Take a look.